# What on earth...? File permissions from files created by Python C code

Tags: python, c, distutils, cpython

If I have the following C code:

```
int main(int argc, char **arg)
{
    int x = open("testfilefromc", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    return 0;
}
```

which when I compile and run not unreasonably creates this:

```
-rw-r-----   1 joewass  staff     0B 31 Jan 21:17 testfilefromc
```

But the following C code, compiled into a Python module:

```
const char *filename = "testfilefrompython";
context->fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
```

does this:

```
----------   1 joewass  staff   165B 31 Jan 21:09 testfilefrompython
```

And not surprisingly the code that created the file can't open it next time round!

Why on earth would the file be created with zero permissions? And why would the behaviour be different in C compiled into a Python module? I'm running the python program that runs the code as me.

For what it's worth, I'm `mmap`ing the file later on.

Thanks!

Joe

**EDIT** :I know I can `chmod` to fix this, the question is *why*?

**EDIT 2**: Thanks to [Rosh Oxymoron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512132/rosh-oxymoron) for pointing out that I missed the not-so-optional optional argument. [TRWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) is that the first example worked at all!

Comment: Maybe you have a call to `umask()` somewhere in your C code?

Comment: Try to run your code under `strace`. Pay attention at `open`/`creat` and `chmod`/`fchmod` calls.

Comment: @Frédéric - no umask in my code. Who knows what Python's doing though!

Comment: @Roman I'm on Mac OS. I'll look into Dtrace, but from what I remember it's not simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `open` takes three arguments. If you specify the `O_CREAT` flag, you need to call it with this signature:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

Otherwise the behaviour is undefined. It's very unlikely for the creation of the file in your first example to work at all. Also take a look at `umask` which is always ANDed with the mode that you specify.

Comment: You are entirely correct. I missed that paragraph in the man page (on Mac it's documented `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);` and I didn't read it thoroughly enough). Thank you!